# Call a function when text inside an element changes using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I would like to execute a function when text inside an element on my page changes. Text in that element is updated by another external JS function hence I dont have any control on that function.

Update : Element is a span.

```
<span class="dynamic">some Text</span>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a work around,

**[Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/afudor/1/edit)**

```
$('#elementId').change(function(){
   alert("changed");
});

var previousVal = "";
function InputChangeListener()
{
   if($('#elementId').val() != previousVal)
   {
     previousVal  = $('#elementId').val();
     $('#elementId').change();    
   }
}

setInterval(InputChangeListener, 500);

$('#elementId').val(3);
```

Comment: Unless this event is triggered by the external JS function when the input is changed, this won't help.

Comment: Hmm, poll the element for a new value every 1/2 second.  That's not a bad idea.

Comment: @thedixon: How would that help?

Comment: Just read the original question again, this answer is correct, my bad.

Comment: Even with the update that the element is a `span`, this should still work!  http://jsbin.com/afudor/3/edit

Comment: Nice hack, It is working for me. But I am afraid of  its performance as it will keep on running again and again after every 30 seconds

Answer (score 1):

try add event on that element

```
$('.target').change(function() {
  alert('Handler for .change() called.');
});
```

details: http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: Unless this event is triggered by the external JS function when the input is changed, this won't help.

Comment: if you can not use exactly this event, you can try use .keypress() or .keyup()

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Your point would apply to all possible methods of doing this, unless polling was used.

Comment: ok, you can add keypress to document/window. And in your function you should check if your element in focus, And if element has focus you will call your function

Comment: @AntonBaksheiev: How would the element's focus help?

Comment: if use pressed key and input filed in focus it means that user changed vakue in this field, but if not you should not call your function. but in this case you should check that user pressed A-Z and 0-9, and not Shift,Alt so on

Comment: @AntonBaksheiev: The input field being updated by an external JS script, *not* by the user.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by having your element bind to the change event and when you set the text value with `text()` you will immediately call `change()` on the element.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/WWuNf/1/

Html:

```
<div id="field">Foo</div>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#field').on('change', function(evt){
        foo();
    }).text('Bar').change();
});

function foo() {
 alert('changed');        
}
```

Edit: This, of course, is when the value of your field is changing by some other means and not by direct user interaction. For something like that you'll need to bind to either `keyup()` or `keypress()`.

Comment: `Text in that element is updated by another external JS function hence I dont have any control on that function`

Answer (score 0):

Given that the `change()` method requires explicitly triggering that event, and that might not always be the case, I thought I'd offer a somewhat clumsy alternative, using mutation events.

In this approach I've set the `body` element to listen for the `DOMCharacterDataModified` event, fired when a `textNode`'s value is changed (this means that it *doesn't*, by design, fire if the `textNode` is removed and replaced). Because I'm using jQuery to do this the...approach of getting to the `textNode` is a little clumsy:

```
$('body').on('DOMCharacterDataModified', 'p', function(e){
    console.log(e.originalEvent.prevValue, e.originalEvent.newValue);
});

$('button').click(
    function(){
        var t = $(this).prev().val();
        document
            .getElementById('test')
            .firstChild.nodeValue += ' ' + t;
    });
​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/dFxXH/3/).

It's important to note that Mutation Events aren't supported in IE below version nine, so while this works (and doesn't require manual event-triggering) it's less reliable cross-browser than simply using a custom event with `trigger()`.

References:

- [Browser compatibility for mutation events.](http://help.dottoro.com/ljfvvdnm.php#additionalEvents).
- [Mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mutation_events).

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#element').on('change', function() {

});
```

Comment: Unless this event is triggered by the external JS function when the input is changed, this won't help.

Comment: Can you explain why? jQuery uses subscribe and publish methods, so whatever happens to that individual element, the change event will be subscribed to it and will fire. What order this is, between jQuery and the external library, I'm not sure of.

Comment: Because if you do `$('input').val('value')`, this will *not* trigger the change event.  You'd need to trigger that event manually.  Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NTICompass/p4saT/1/

Comment: That depends on what you count as triggered, if you change the input, then lose focus, the event will fire - which is what the event is for. "onkeyup" can be used for instant changes to the text inside the text area.

Comment: `Text in that element is updated by another external JS function hence I dont have any control on that function.`  I'm assuming this external function is using `.val()` to update the value, therefore `onkeyup` won't help.  And I'm also assuming the element didn't have focus before the external function changed its value.